# Cordova plugin method get hold/stops while webview scrolled and touchmove event

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, scroll, phonegap-plugins

I am working on  an application which is using phonegap  to show map native (MKMapView) in front of the webview.

Because the map view is in static position and my web view doesn't use overflow css properties, I created a plugin which will set the frame of the map every time I scroll the webview.

But the problem is after I investigate it, the cordova plugin method gets hold/doesn't execute while I scroll the webview using touchmove event and after I finish scrolling it all the method which has been hold get called together. Is there any suggestion to solve this problem?

For the code at plugin :

`- (void) testMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {
    CDVPluginResult *result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"called from plugin callback"];
    NSLog(@"called from plugin");
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
}`

For the code at javascript :

```
$('body').on('touchmove',function() {
        cordova.exec(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, 'TestPlugin', 'testMethod', []);
    });
```

Comment: your question is not too clear . Dont understand what do you exactly want achieve using the testMethod ?

Comment: i call the testMethod using touchmove event at the webview (using javascript) but the testMethod from the cordova plugin doesnt called directly and get hold until i leave my touch from the webview.